# Observer Pattern With Counter Observer?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I have an Observer and a Subject per usual Observer Pattern.

However I also need to inform the Subject of events happening in the Observer.

What I'm trying to achieve is a decoupled bi-directional decision mechanism that is informed by events.

Both Observer and Subject is connected to larger systems.

Currently I'm using the Subject sending events to Observer and flags the other way.

Should I be setting a counter-observer or is there a better way?

Platform: Unity 3D

Comment: In general I would claim this is probably pretty opinion-based ... I had something like this in the past and we ended up saying - since the Subject doesn't know the Observer but the other way round the Observer knows the Subject anyway, there speaks nothing against explicitly also passing back feedback from the Observer to the Subject via calling a dedicated method on the Subject (via interface so it is still only loosely coupled). You could of course also plug a mediator between them .. I'd say depends on your own preferences and conventions

Comment: Good to know, maybe a Communicator Pattern that acts like a radio would be an improvement. Currently Observer-Counter-Observer worked for me because my system is a bit complicated in terms of who talks to who. Working fine with multiple instances and the clutter is minimal. Glad to hear more alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

We can notify **Subject** from **Observer** by a reference to  **Subject** that each observer has.

Let me show an example via C#. This is our abstractions:

```
public interface IMyObserver
{
    public void Update(string myMessage);

    public void NotifySubject(string message);
}

public interface IMySubject
{
    public void RegisterObserver(IMyObserver o);

    public void RemoveObserver(IMyObserver o);

    public void NotifyObservers();

    public void NotifyMe(string messageFromObserver);
}
```

And its concrete implementations of `MyObserver`:

```
public class MyObserver : IMyObserver
{
    private MySubject _mySubject;
    private string _myMessage;

    public MyObserver(MySubject mySubject)
    {
        _mySubject = mySubject;
        _mySubject.RegisterObserver(this);
    }

    public void NotifySubject(string message)
    {
        _mySubject.NotifyMe(message);
    }

    public void Update(string myMessage)
    {
        _myMessage = myMessage;
        Console.WriteLine($"Observer have seen this message: {_myMessage}");
    }
}
```

And `MySubject` looks like this:

```
public class MySubject : IMySubject
{
    private List<IMyObserver> _observers;
    private string _myMessage;
    private string _messageFromObserver;

    public MySubject() => _observers = new List<IMyObserver>();

    public void NotifyObservers()
    {
        foreach (IMyObserver observer in _observers)
            observer.Update(_myMessage);
    }

    public void RegisterObserver(IMyObserver o) => _observers.Add(o);

    public void RemoveObserver(IMyObserver o) => _observers.Remove(o);

    public void MyMessageChanged() => NotifyObservers();

    public void SetMessage(string message)
    {
        _myMessage = message;
        MyMessageChanged();
    }

    public string GetMessage() => _myMessage;

    public void NotifyMe(string messageFromObserver)
    {
        _messageFromObserver = messageFromObserver;
        Console.WriteLine($"Subject received this message from observer: 
            {_messageFromObserver}");
    }
}
```

The above code can be called like this:

```
MySubject mySubject = new ();
MyObserver myObserver = new (mySubject);

// message from subject
mySubject.SetMessage("Hello World!"); // OUTPUT: Observer have seen this message: 
    // Hello World!

// message from observer to subject
myObserver.NotifySubject("We are notifying subject"); ; // OUTPUT: Subject 
    // received this message from observer: We are notifying subject
```